# Star Micronics iOS Sdk, can't print on background thread

Tags: ios, printing, thermal-printer

I wanna know if anyone managed to print raster graphics to Star Micronics thermal printers using the StarIO sdk on a background thread? I tried to do that and the printer just won't print.

This is quite annoying because each time I try to print something to the printer, the entire app will just freeze until the operation is done, usually on a LAN connected printer it won't be that noticable, but on a bluetooth thermal printer it's unacceptable.

Thanks

Comment: I have a very limited exp with star printers with cash drawers and have had issues with them always like not able to print by giving command on same link twice etc.. Since you are using them then you or your client must have paid for there sdk license best bet is to mail their tech team

Comment: HI wahkiz..How to print a pdf by using this SDK.??.it is really confusing..If you know please guide me..

Comment: @amar, The SDK is a free download from their website. We only paid for the hardware, which does not include technical support.

Comment: @satya, To print a PDF, just render it into an UIImage, which the StarIO SDK accepts as raster printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/opentable/star-printing for an example of using NSBlockOperation and an NSOperationQueue to run your print jobs on a background thread. They also have a great wrapper around the StarIO framework that is much easier to use.

Comment: Since the time I asked the question, I have switched to using star-printing by Open Table when I saw it popped in github. I am glad to report it works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own driver to get around several problems I had with the Star supplied driver. It does print on background threads.

https://github.com/gabebear/TSPPrintingExample

Comment: Thanks for notifying me about this library of yours. I would take it for a spin. Currently the star-printing library from OpenTable lacks multiple printer support and seems to have some problems with printing to a bluetooth printer.

Comment: Mine doesn't handle the Star Bluetooth printers yet at all, but multiple printers is something I've tested pretty well. I have a prototype app printing to the Star T300i working... but it's a bit buggy(refuses to print some stuff). I don't think I'll bother working on the existing bluetooth more since I'm hoping they'll release a Bluetooth LE version(which would fit my company's use cases much better).